# Why does the XFORCEVESA command throw me onto the command line?

Tags: 10.10, graphics

Hey all. I've suffered a major problem with my laptop over the last release or so; which is solved by appending xforcevesa to the boot options.

However, in 10.10, instead of putting me onto low graphics mode, it instead puts me onto the command line. Help!

Comment: What hardware and video drivers are you using?  If you're using a kms-enabled driver, did you try disabling KMS?

Comment: Well, after doing a bit more digging, I ticked the 'nomodeset' option in boot options. I do actually seem to load Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Jorge, I would but this isn't so much a solution as a quickfix :/

Answer (score 1):

As a solution to your immediate problem you can use nomodeset in your boot options instead of xforcevesa.

I'd also report your problems to the xorg bug list: https://bugs.launchpad.net/xorg and upstream at https://bugs.freedesktop.org/describecomponents.cgi?product=xorg making sure to give the reports as much information about your hardware as possible.

You might be asked to try out the updated xorg/drivers and you can find some of these available here: https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa which will upgrade various things to their latest versions.

Comment: nomodeset does exactly the same thing :/ I filed a bug sometime ago, but no progress has been made; perhaps you might be able to help? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/+bug/605414